# Bash Execute command in string which include 'read', read can not read input from the stdin

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

I write a shell script named as `test.sh` :

```
#!/bin/bash
read MY_NAME
echo $MY_NAME
```

When i execute by file, such as:

```
./test.sh
```

everything is ok, but if i execute it by string ,such as:

```
cat ./test.sh | sh
```

there is nothing output. Read command did not work when I Execute command using string. How can i fixed it ?

So, if i want execute the script with string and read some value from the stdin, how to work ?

Answer (score 3):

When you execute the script by a shell running in a pipeline, the stdin of the shell is connected to the pipe, so `read` reads from the pipe, but there's nothing, as everything has already been read by the shell (or worse, if the script is long enough, `read` might eat part of it before the shell reads it).

BTW, don't run `bash` scripts with `sh`, on many systems, `sh` and `bash` aren't identical.

Comment: Even worse, if the script is long enough, `sh` might not read the entire script, allowing the `read` command (when executed) to consume a line of the script.

Comment: And even if `sh` and `bash` are identical, `bash` will behave differently when invoked as `sh`.

Comment: So, if i want execute the script with string and read some value from the stdin, how to work ?